# Why is using 'this' mid-sentence incorrect?

Tags: grammar

I am an English Literature teacher at university level, and a trained EFL teacher, so it's a bit embarrassing to have to ask this, but I can't find a satisfying answer anywhere else.

My students regularly use 'this' mid-sentence, usually after a comma. E.g., 'The room is small, this indicates that...'

I think it should read: 'The room is small. This indicates that...' *or* 'The room is small, which indicates that...'

I am fully aware of the rules (whether you adhere to them or otherwise) that govern the use of 'that' and 'which', but I've yet to find a convincing way to explain to my students that 'this' is incorrect mid-sentence.

At the moment I try to explain that 'this' should only follow a full stop or semi-colon as it refers to the subject of the preceding clause, but that's not actually an explanation of *why* 'this' is incorrect mid-sentence.

Of course, I may be completely wrong, and it's actually fine to use 'this' in this way.

Can anyone help with an explanation that I can offer my students?

Comment: The violation of punctuation conventions is easily addressed. A thornier problem is the fact that the referent for "this" is not always going to be clear.  For that reason, it would be better to have the students avoid "this" and attempt to rephrase the idea, e.g. "The smallness of the room indicates..."

Comment: As @Languagemaven points out, it's a "comma splice". But so is, for example, [*It's not a comet, it's a meteor*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22It%27s+not+a+comet%2C+it%27s+a+meteor%22). I rather like Barbara Wallraff's observation on that one: [*Punctuating this sentence with a semicolon would be like using a C-clamp to hold a sandwich together.*](http://archive.wilsonquarterly.com/book-reviews/grammar-style) My point being that you can't simply say *It's a comma splice, **that's** why it's "ungrammatical".*

Comment: You could throw all kinds of grammatical rules at your students—which usually has no effect—or encourage them to learn to *listen*. "The room is small, this indicates …" is awkward to pronounce as a running sentence, with a large pause between the two parts—the kind of pause that's indicated by a period. Punctuation is better learned through listening, imho.

Comment: @ralph.m: Listening AND talking. Nothing registers without  feedback loop.

Comment: @Ricky—yeah, I meant "listing to themselves".

Comment: Fumblefingers raises a good point -- that writers will often wittingly use comma splices for rhetorical effect. However, I'm not sure how much of an effect they're really achieving in doing so (it's just a punctuation mark after all) and find the analogy of using a C-clamp to hold a sandwich together (while nice and vivid) hyperbolic to say the least.

Comment: @ralph.m. I beg to differ: the feedback loop is key. Listen to others/talk to others. Those who are excessively fond of hearing their own voices should use voice recorders.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I often try to get students to read their work aloud to 'hear' where the punctuation should go. Honestly, it's a job to get them to even proofread their essays (don't get me started on the misuse of even the basics like commas and apostrophes), and as a university teacher I only have very limited contact time with them in which to convince them of the importance of doing so. I will take your advice and condense it into a pithy 'Quickmark' for Turnitin (online marking system) and hope that at least one reads it. Or I may resort to sniping emails...

Comment: Why is using ‘this’ mid-sentence deemed wrong? What about phrases like, “What do you think of **this** piece of art?”

Comment: Or the sentence you wrote that violates your rules: "Of course, I may be completely wrong, and it's actually fine to use 'this' in this way."

Comment: @Martin Bean, Darren Gourley: The OP isn't stating it's never correct for the word 'this' to appear mid-sentence. They're asking about a specific usage, where it's seemingly incorrect mid-sentence, and seemingly correct at the beginning of a sentence. The title can only include so much information about what's being asked, which is why there's a body to the question.

Comment: Here's another reason:  which is a *connective* while this is not.  A connective (yet, which, etc.) can be used to indicate that the clause that follows is actually a part of the current thought (and sentence).  Using `this` instead turns it into a run-on sentence with a comma in it. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comma splice question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212708/comma-splice-question)

Answer (score 27):

It's because you can't use a comma to separate two independent clauses without their being joined by a conjunction, etc. The type of sentence construction your students are writing is known as a "[comma splice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice)".

Comment: Probably worth mentiong that there are plentyof cases where 'this' can occur outside the restrictions the OP specifies, especially when there is a valid congunction. e.g. "The student failed, but this was because of health issues".

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: In paragraph 5 the OP gives his policy on the use of 'this' mid-sentence, which I believe is over-restrictive. Thought you might like to add that to your answer. It's not worth my making a separate answer for.

Comment: Gotcha, although rather than add it to my answer, I'd say it might be better for you to comment on it under the post itself (since you're taking issue with that specific paragraph of the OP).

Comment: But people can, and they do.

Comment: Right, just as people can, and do, make themselves intelligible...but no, not you

Comment: Comma splicing seems to be on the rise lately, and I _hate_ it :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit.  Then don't do it... Or are you trying to be funny.

Comment: @Languagemaven I doubt two people would upvote a comment that was unintelligible.

Comment: @jobermark: Sorry, what? What makes you think I was "trying to be funny"? More and more people are comma splicing, and I hate it. What's difficult to understand about that statement?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "X, and Y" splices the sentence "X.  And Y."  Comma splicing is a time-honored tradition.  It is best when ideas are closely related, and the sentences short.  But it is what we do when we use commas before 'and' and 'but'.

Comment: @jobermark: Complete nonsense..... That's not a comma splice, and those aren't sentences. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice

Comment: Well I'm happy to see that jobermark has finally decided to communicate with us :-) Anyway, I wouldn't go so far as to say it's a "time-honored tradition." But I think he's right that many respectable writers have done it, especially when the sentences are short. Still, I would question why there's really that much of a need to do it. What's so much different about using a semicolon? Does a comma add that much more rhetorical spice because it's shorter?

Comment: IMO it's not the same type of thing as, say, writing in incomplete sentences (e.g., "Absolutely," or "Over the rainbow, man"), which can obviously have such great rhetorical effect in context. Just some thoughts.

Comment: Sure.  There are three or four levels of separation in English (depending upon your opinion of dashes and ellipses.)  You can always just go with separate sentences.  Each step down risks a loss of clarity.  (And even Rathony has a point.  Coordinating conjunctions do make it safer to step down without confusion, although they are still never required.)  But concerns about moving closer to spoken English are all relative choices, not rules.  "I came, I saw, I conquered." *is not* better written as three sentences.  Yes, those are sentences, and yes combining them is an option.

Comment: _"I came; I saw; I conquered"_ is a/the "correct" version of that so-called "sentence", @jobermark, as you well know.

Comment: Fowler's original says that it is “roughly true that grammatically independent sentences should be parted by at least a semicolon; but […] there are very large exceptions to this”.  I will go with famous commentary on grammar over you.  It is only roughly true, *not a rule*, and the exceptions are *very large*.  I will go with Fowler over you.

Comment: Funny how he's been dead for almost a century.

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing better than a dictionary when explaining to others in terms of grammatical usages.

If you look up "[this](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/this)", there is a specific usage which is similar to yours:

> Referring to a specific thing just mentioned: '***They*** build the car in
>   their Turin plant, ***and this*** brings the expected levels of
>   quality.'

The dictionary uses "and" after a comma. This is an example that students should follow.

There is another example that doesn't use "and" after a comma as follows:

> ***This*** is not a role model, ***this*** is a terrifying ideologue and a
>   fundamentalist, if you will.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Here, "and" is not used because the subject of the second clause is the same as the first clause.

You have to explain to your students:

> You can only omit "and" after a comma when the subject of the previous clause is
>   the same as that of the second clause.

Comment: The second fragment needs a semicolon, IMO.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for you comment. I sometimes wonder why one of them is not dying out.

Comment: Dictionaries are good for meaning. They don't normally get into details about grammar. You got lucky that there were relevant examples in that particular dictionary ... but even here it's sub-optimal, as it doesn't tell you why those examples are correct and the student's usage is not. (You can't expect the dictionary to list *every* correct sentence form, so not listing it doesn't tell you much.)

Comment: @R.M. What is your point? Is your English better than Oxford Dictionary? Or do you write better than those sentences in it?

Comment: @Rathony There *is* something better than a dictionary when explaining grammatical usage: an actual grammar book. While dictionary examples may be grammatical (for the most part - many examples in the OED are archaic), they don't necessarily outline the full extent of what is and is not grammatical. Just because they omit an example with a particular construction or give an example with a different construction, that doesn't mean that the original construction is forbidden. -- The student's example is, indeed, bad grammar, but there's nothing on that dictionary page which says that.

Comment: @Rathony The examples you give aren't archaic, but some actual examples from the "[this](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/200894)" page of the OED are: "Þis sigbecn þun setton." "This of Bavaria is a gallant and polite court." "This was years ago, Four hundred, full." (Note the OED and the Oxford Dictionary of English are distinct, but from the same publisher.) - Both dictionaries and grammar books take examples from the English language corpus (not from each other), but each focuses on different features and is optimized for different purposes.

Comment: @Rathony I suspect we may be talking cross purposes. I don't have an issue with your conclusions, mainly just your first sentence. "I looked up 'this' and was lucky enough to find example sentences which will help me explain things." would be fine, but to me it reads more "Pro tip: in the future, you can answer such questions yourself by just looking up the word in the dictionary; it will tell you if things are grammatical or not." The latter is not generalizable advice, for the above-stated reasons.

Comment: The 'and' is not an important part of the grammar here.  You are inventing a rule with little support that simply does not exist.  All your examples are comma-splices, and 'this' can refer equally well to the prior subject or the prior clause as a whole whether or not there is a conjunction there, and whehter there is period, a semicolon or a comma between the clauses.

Comment: Give some evidence this is a real rule and not a spurious and bias observation first.   Your examples are all comma-splices of two sentences.  'And' is an optional way to start the second sentence.  There is no rule.  This construct is perfectly good, just awkward because it is less clear than using 'that' or 'which'.

Answer (score 4):

This is not quite an answer but rather a hypothesis that might prove helpful to you. If not, don't kill me.

As Lunguagemaven pointed out, technically, your students seem to be excessively fond of the comma splice. In reality, they're merely accustomed to talking (and thinking) in short block-like sentences that follow one another in quick succession. They are loath to pause after each sentence lest their listeners take advantage of it and start talking themselves. The resulting patterspeak is reflected in their writing.

One way to remedy this would be to teach them to write longer, more descriptive sentences (adjectives and adverbs galore). Instead of letting them write "This room is small," insist on details, metaphors, humor - anything. "This otherwise perfectly serviceable room with off-white walls and quaint-looking windows is ludicrously small." It would be pretty difficult not to pause and take a breath after a sentence of this length. And, just like "a good cigar is a smoke," a good dramatic pause is an invitation to put a period where it belongs.

Comment: The more likely reason they like 'this' in place of 'that' or 'which' is that the distinctions are different in English from those in most other languages.  Also, It is officially correct in a wider variety of places.  (As it is correct here.)  But we prefer the other two, more specific forms for exactly that reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule is overly broad. A case could be made for applying it to the example you give, but as a rule to state in such a broad way it is very flawed.

For example *this* sentence uses the word mid-sentence. What does *this* mean? I think that *this* means your rule doesn't work. Isn't *this* neat? I think that *this* rule needs to be thrown out. I don't know how *this* impacts your teaching, but *this* is still the case. I think I'm done with *this* answer.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, it is not ungrammatical, it is just awkward.

The 'this' does not refer to the subject of the preceding clause, *but to the whole clause itself*.

The which/that distinction helps us in situations like this:

> The parking space has a sign that [the sign] indicates it is for small cars.
>
> The parking space has a sign, which [the *clause*] indicates it is special (even to those who cannot read.)

But not choosing means:

> The parking space has a sign.  This [which one?] indicates...

Many people only use this construction when they want to be pedantic.  They are slowing you down by not giving expected grammatical clues.

Doing that *and* comma-splicing at the same time is not incorrect, it is just mean.